# Fourier transform using principal value

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, integral-transforms

Can anyone help me  compute the Fourier transform of $ 1/|x|^{n-\alpha} $ in $\mathbb{R}^n $ where $ 0 < \alpha < n $ ? Somehow it becomes the principal value of $ 1/|x|^\alpha $ which I can't figure out.

Comment: Hint: Isn't $1/|x|^{n-\alpha}$ regarded as a *frequency* versus $|x|$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not all that simple a calculation. A standard technique (see, e.g., Stein's *Singular Integrals*, III.3) is to remember that the Fourier transform of the Gaussian is another Gaussian, and to use that as an auxiliary function. That is to say, if

$$f(x) = e^{-\pi \delta |x|^2},$$ then
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \delta^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{-\frac{\pi |\xi|^2}{\delta}}.$$

This is useful because if one invokes a change of variable in the definition of the Gamma function one retrieves the following identity:
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\pi \delta |x|^2} \delta^{\beta -1} d\delta = \frac{\Gamma(\beta)}{(\pi|x|^2)^\beta}$$
Taking the Fourier transform of the above expression with respect to $x$ yields
$$\int_0^\infty \delta^{\beta - \frac{n}{2} -1} e^{- \pi |\xi|^2 / \delta} d\delta = \int_0^\infty s^{-1 + \frac{n}{2} -\beta} e^{-\pi s |\xi|^2} ds = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} -\beta)}{(\pi |\xi|^2)^{\frac{n}{2} -\beta}} $$
Setting $\beta = \frac{n-\alpha}{2}$, we get the desired result.

Comment: And the inevitability of the result follows from nice general properties of Fourier transform: $1/|x|^{n-\alpha}$ is a tempered distribution, rotation-invariant, and homogeneous under dilations. Fourier transform preserves rotation-invariance, and converts homogeneity of degree $n-\alpha$ to $\alpha$. Then the constant can be determined by the computation at the end of @RayYang's answer.

Comment: @RayYang How did you identify your expression with the fourier transform of $ 1/|x|^{n-\alpha} $ ?

Comment: Um, which specific part of the above is unclear, smiley?

Comment: Got it now, thanks.